# Cross Compiling using Mingw on an autotools and Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, cross-compiling, autotools

So I'm running on Fedora and I have a autotools project that compiles fine for linux. I was trying to get it to cross compile for windows today using mingw and I running into undefined reference problems. It turns out when I do my ./configure --host=mingw... my AC_CHECK_LIBS are failing for -lQtCore and a few others libs. I've been googling all morning to no avail.

It seems TrollTech wants people to use Qmake? But what I have read doesn't help. I have installed mingw-qt. Any ideas what might be causing the issue? Let me know what additional output/pieces of information I can provide to help you understand this question.

Comment: What is the output of AC_CHECK_LIBS in config.h?

Comment: *Sighs* After spending all morning working on this I discover my error 5 minutes after posting here :-)

Anyways, for reference the problem was while my linux had qt4 as -lQtCore etc the mingw tool chain was expecting -lQtCore4....

Comment: You might consider the purchase of a rubber duck :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem It was while my linux had qt4 as -lQtCore etc the mingw tool chain was expecting -lQtCore4.